# How to check and change the DateTime Format from UK to US in an excel sheet using C#?

Tags: c#

I have  .Net code which retrieves a set of data/records in a GridView and renders it to the User. There are a couple of columns comprising of dates. When, i export this data into the excel having users regional settings set to that of UK, DateTime format for the columns remains fine. But, when it gets exported to the computers having US regional settings, the columns in excel formats changes and anything exceeding 12 in the 'DD' gets left-aligned in the excel column as it is Month for the US settings. In short, i wanted to first check and then change the format as per the individual user's region settings. I'v been scratching my head with Culture's but with no output. Appreciate any help on this? Here is what i'm trying to do:

```
enter code here
```

protected void gvReportHidden_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        CultureInfo currentCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;

```
    if (currentCulture.NativeName.Equals("en-UK"))
        {
            e.Row.Cells[8].Text = DateTime.Parse(e.Row.Cells[8].Text).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            e.Row.Cells[9].Text = DateTime.Parse(e.Row.Cells[9].Text).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        }
        else
        {
            e.Row.Cells[8].Text = DateTime.Parse(e.Row.Cells[8].Text).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
            e.Row.Cells[9].Text = DateTime.Parse(e.Row.Cells[9].Text).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        }
}
```

Comment: Please share your code so we can see what you have tried rather than speculating

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to explicity set the culture when you output the DateTime variable. Here is an example from MSDN:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;

public class TestClass
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

      DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
      Console.WriteLine("Today is {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("d"));

      // Increments dt by one day.
      dt = dt.AddDays(1);
      Console.WriteLine("Tomorrow is {0}", dt.ToString("d"));

   }
}

//If you execute this code on August 3, 2001, it displays the following output:


Today is 8/3/2001
Tomorrow is 8/4/2001
```

And a quick google search turns up the list of culture available:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.80).aspx

List is very long so I didn't post it, but you should be able to find the UK culture code easily enough

Comment: Thanks for this quick reply, however, what i'm trying to do is, setting the property of the specified column in a gridview to the US format from UK. And the records comes from the database and directly displays the record in the format 'DD/MM/YYYY'. I want to handle this and display DateTime in the US format. Thanks!

Comment: If you have a DateTime object with a value then you can put it into any format you want, use the en-US culture string and you can also throw in any other formatting you need

Comment: @PseuduNym01 : Thanks for the help here. I am getting an error in the else part stating "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime" :- System.FormatException while trying to parse the object to that of US datetime(local settings are same as of US). Is it possible to parse datetime to US. How? Thanks!